# Run a function on each element in a list and output answer using cons

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a function that takes in a list and passes each element in the list to another function that returns a number value. I need the function that takes in a list to output the resulting list similar to how `map` works.

Here's what I have so far but it's giving me unexpected output.

```
(define (lister x)
  (cond ((null? x) '())
  (cons (solver (car x)) (lister (cdr x))) )
)

(lister '(
  (element 0)
  (element 3)
))
```

The expected output should be `'(0 3)` but it's returning `'()`.

Comment: It's just an arbitrary function that returns the number in `(element x)`. So for example, `solver` for `(element 0)` returns `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cond` usage is wrong.

Try:

```
(define (lister x)
  (cond [(null? x) '()]
    [else (cons (solver (car x)) (lister (cdr x)))]
  ) 
)
```

or use `if`:

```
(define (lister x)
  (if (null? x) 
    '()
    (cons (solver (car x)) (lister (cdr x))) 
  )
)
```